# create array using push and split and for loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Please see my below code.

```
graph_data = 30,, [.00, 3.20],, 'Driving',,10,, [3.20, 5.17],,'Off-Duty';

var numbersArray = graph_data.split(',,');
var sritems = [];

for(var i=0;i<numbersArray.length;i++){
    var j = i;
    var k = j+1;
    var m = k+1;

    sritems.push({
      "x" : numbersArray[j],
      "y" : numbersArray[k],
      "label" : numbersArray[m]
    });
          i=m;
}
```

I want result like below.

```
{x: 30, y:[.00, 3.20], label: "Driving"},{x: 10, y:[3.20, 5.17], label: "Off-Duty"}
```

I can able to set graph_data variable value as per requirement.

Comment: Your assignment to `graph_data` isn't valid. You're missing quotes around the value.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I fetching from variable so we don't required that.

Comment: It gives me this error in console : Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` too much, because you set it to `m+1` in the body, and then add `1` again in the `for` loop header.

To convert the string in the first field to a number, use `parseInt`. To convert the string into a second field, use `JSON.parse()` (but make sure the numbers are valid JSON -- they need a digit before the decimal point). And to convert the string in the third field, remove the surrounding quotes.

```js
graph_data = "30,, [0.00, 3.20],, 'Driving',,10,, [3.20, 5.17],,'Off-Duty'";

var numbersArray = graph_data.split(',,');
var sritems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i += 3) {
  var j = i;
  var k = j + 1;
  var m = k + 1;

  sritems.push({
    "x": parseInt(numbersArray[j], 10),
    "y": JSON.parse(numbersArray[k]),
    "label": numbersArray[m].trim().slice(1, -1) // Remove surrounding quotes
  });
}
alert(JSON.stringify(sritems, 2));
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to trim the spaces around the elements, and remove the quotes around the label. Run the snippet to see.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but it gives me same error in console.Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type in canvasjs.js

Comment: You realize that `split()` returns strings, don't you? The string `[0.00, 3.20]` is not an array, which is probably what the code you're passing this array to expects.

Comment: You need to add more code that parses that into an array. It could almost be done using `JSON.parse()`, execpt that `.00` is not a valid number in JSON -- it needs to be `0.00`.

Comment: And i even don't want " in X and Y as well as value of that.

Comment: Ok then i can change .00 to 0.00. that's fine for me.

Comment: and if i right     sritems.push({
      "x" : 30,
      "y" : [.00, 3.20],
      "label" : 'Driving'
      });   then it display perfect.

Comment: I got the point.. you are 90% right. but now i don't want " in value of X and Y. That's it.

Comment: Call `parseInt(numberArrays[j], 10)` to convert the string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sritems.push({
  "x": numbersArray[i],
  "y": numbersArray[++i],
  "label": numbersArray[++i]
});
```

This way you won't need `j,k,m`.

As it stands, I believe your code skips a value.

Comment: i tried but not working. it aleary alert all values. its perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```js
graph_data = "30,, [0.00, 3.20],, 'Driving',,10,, [3.20, 5.17],,'Off-Duty'";

var numbersArray = graph_data.split(',,');
var sritems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i += 3) {
  var j = i;
  var k = j + 1;
  var m = k + 1;

  sritems.push({
    "x": parseInt(numbersArray[j], 10),
    "y": JSON.parse(numbersArray[k]),
    "label": numbersArray[m].trim().slice(1, -1) // Remove surrounding quotes
  });
}
alert(JSON.stringify(sritems, 2));
```